# Reassigning different type to variables in Go

Tags: go

Looking to do something like this

```
curr := foo()["blah"].(string)
curr, err := strconv.ParseFloat(curr, 64)
```

`ERROR: cannot assign float64 to curr (type string) in multiple assignment`

I dont want to make another temporary variable that I won't use after the conversion. I'm fairly new to Go so is there an approach that will help me avoid

```
temp := foo()["blah"].(string)
curr, err := strconv.ParseFloat(temp, 64)
```

Comment: It's not possible in the same *scope*, but you can create arbitrary scopes with curly braces https://play.golang.org/p/M47wcq2cCZO.

Comment: @mkopriva is this bad practice?

Comment: Not sure if it's bad, but it most certainly isn't good. The proper way would be the one you don't want to take.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah didn't think so either. Thanks, I'll go stick to the second approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to force duck-typing here, and Go is statically-typed so that's going to be hairy or impossible. This justifies having another variable:

```
if temp, ok := foo()["blah"].(string); ok {
        curr, err := strconv.ParseFloat(temp, 64)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}
```

Go garbage collector is pretty sick. Having an extra variable `temp` for a few lines isn't that bad. Also don't forget guarding over type assertion.

Comment: What's the point of `var curr string` if you're redeclaring it in the `if`'s scope? Or did you mean to use `=` and have `err` also declared outside?

Comment: that was `err` being defined. In multiple assignments, either one of the left-hand tokens that's being declared/defined needs a `:=` and `err` was never declared elsewhere. If we wanted to throw away `err` like `curr, _ = ...` then `=` makes sense.

Comment: Not really true, at least not if the redeclaration is happening in a new scope, even if it's a subscope https://play.golang.org/p/o6pN0R13RQM

Comment: @mkopriva you're right. Both variables were defined and `curr` shadowed over the global one.